# Lazy Loading with Doctrine2 and Symfony2 using DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a tree structure with a parent field. Currently I am trying to get all parent nodes to display the path to the current node.

Basically I am doing a while-loop to process all nodes.

```php
$current = $node->getParent();
while($current) {
  // do something
  $current = $current->getParent();
}
```

Using the default `findById` method works. Because the entity has some aggregated fields, I am using a custom repository method, to load all basic fields with one query.

```php
public function findNodeByIdWithMeta($id) {
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT p, a, c, cc, ca, pp FROM
            TestingNestedObjectBundle:NestedObject p
            JOIN p.actions a
            LEFT JOIN p.children c
            LEFT JOIN c.children cc
            LEFT JOIN c.actions ca
            LEFT JOIN p.parent pp
            WHERE p.id = :id
        ')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->setHint(
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
            'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
        )
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

With that code, loading the parents fails. I only get the immediate parent (addressed by `LEFT JOIN p.parent pp`) but not the parents above. E.g. `$node->getParent()->getParent()` returns `null`.

Whats wrong with my code? Did I misunderstood the lazy loading thing?

Thanks a lot,
Hacksteak

Comment: You've checked that `$node->getParent()` actually _has_ a parent in the database, I presume?

Comment: Have you taken a look at doctrine `nested set` functionality? It sounds very similar to what you are asking. https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1-documentation/blob/master/manual/en/hierarchical-data.txt

Comment: Can you share your database model

Comment: For database performance and scalability, joins are the devil. This one is going to get really slow in a hurry as you database grows. Consider denormalizing it.

Comment: Oh damn, has been a long time since my last vist. Thanks for the replies. In the mean time I solved the described situation by using the gedmo tree extension. But the main question is still unsolved... why did lazy loading fail by using the shown query? I'll look if I have still the sources to post them...

Comment: In the mapping of your entity, is `parent` self-referenced?

Comment: Hey hacksteak25, could you please post your solution (using Tree component)? Many thanks

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your are using the [adjacency model](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql) for storing trees in a relational database. Which in turn means, that you will need a join for every level to get all ancestors with a single query.

As you are already using the [Doctrine Extension Library](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) I recommend to have a look at the [Tree](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) component.

Answer (score 2):

My Answer involves not using DQL and instead creating a NestedSetManager which has access to your DBAL connection so you can use SQL. I never felt like the ORM's did a good job with NestedSets query logic.

With a `NestedSetManager`, you can then write a bunch of clean methods and it's really simple because all these queries are well documented. See [this link](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). Some of the method in my NestedSetManager are:

```
setNode();
setRoot();
loadNestedSet();
moveNodeUp();
modeNodeDown();
getRootNode();
addNodeSibling();
getNodesByDepth();
getParents();
getNodePath();
childExists();
addChildToNode();
renameNode();
deleteNode();
// And many more
```

You can have a ball and create a lot of create NestedSet functionality if you're not tied down by an ORM's somewhat complex functionality.

Also -- Symfony2 makes all this really really easy. You create your NestedSetManager class file and reference it in your Services.yml and pass in your Dbal connection. Mine looks like this:

```
services:
    manager.nestedset:
        class: Acme\CoreBundle\Manager\NestedSetManager
        arguments: [ @database_connection ]
```

you can then access your nestedsets with:

```
$path = $this->get('manager.nestedset')->setNode(4)->getNodePath(); // in your controller
```

Moral of the story, ORM/NestedSets drove me bonkers and this solution work really well. If you're being forced to use DQL and have no other options, this answer probably wont be acceptable.